# How to repeat input in python?

Tags: python-3.7

I want to keep inputting numbers without breaking the execution of program so my program can say if the number is even or odd for every input. It just does it once and it breaks. Please help!

I've been trying the while and continue but no luck so far.

```
print('Please enter a number so I can check if it is even or odd.')
number = int(input())
mod = number % 2

if mod > 0:
    print('This number is odd.')
else:
    print('This number is even.')
```

I expect to keep inputting numbers non-stop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    print('Please enter a number so I can check if it is even or odd.')
    number = int(input())
    mod = number % 2

    if mod > 0:
        print('This number is odd.')
    else:
        print('This number is even.')
```

This will work in your case

Answer (score -1):

You use def function

```
def m(number):
       if(number == "exit"):
                   return
        else:
              Num=number%2
              If( m>0):
                   print("odd")
               else:
                     print("even')
        return m(number)
```